# How can i minimized the code for hovering the images and showing the content. jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

My code is very repetitive. I just want to minimize it but I don't know how to do it. Everything is working fine, I just want my code not to be so repetitive.

```js
$(".thumbs").hover(function() {
  $(".project__description").removeClass("hidden__");
  $(".project__description__small").removeClass("hidden__");    
}, function() {
  $(".project__description").addClass("hidden__");
  $(".project__description__small").addClass("hidden__");
});

$(".thumbs2").hover(function() {
  $(".project__description2").removeClass("hidden__");
  $(".project__description__small2").removeClass("hidden__");
}, function() {
  $(".project__description2").addClass("hidden__");
  $(".project__description__small2").addClass("hidden__");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container__projects" id="commercial">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 animated slideInLeft thumbs">
      <img class="project__images" src="img/commercial/amadeus/a1.jpg" />
      <span class="project__description hidden__">Amadeus Headquarters</span><br>
      <span class="project__description__small hidden__">Interior Design & Supply Services</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 animated slideInRight thumbs2">
      <img class="project__images" src="img/commercial/nadine/a1.jpg" />
      <span class="project__description2 hidden__">Nadine Jewellery</span><br>
      <span class="project__description__small2 hidden__">Interior Design Supply & Execution</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your code currently work?  Can you make a working example?  Are you asking how to make it "better"?  If so, this question is off topic for StackOverflow and would be better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) as you are asking about refactoring working code and not about an error

Comment: Also note that if this is just showing and hiding the `span` elements then it can be done more efficiently in CSS alone

Comment: Hi yes, my code is working properly. but I just want to make it cleaner, because I have 12 items for the gallery, so I will repeat this code around 12 times. they say repeating the same code is not advisable. so that's it.

Comment: Right, so you are asking about refactoring it to make it better.  Which is not an error.  This is why it is off topic.

Comment: ok, sorry for asking a question like this.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you from asking the question.  I just want to make sure you ask it in the right place, :)

Answer (score 2):

To simplify this with jQuery you can firstly combine the selectors with commas.  Then you can place common classes on all instances of the elements, ie. without the `2` or other suffixes, and then use those classes in the jQuery selectors.

To only affect the `span` elements within the `.thumb` which was hovered use the `this` reference to the current element along with `find()` to traverse the DOM, something like this:

```js
$(".thumbs").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".project__description, .project__description__small").removeClass("hidden__");
}, function() {
  $(this).find(".project__description, .project__description__small").addClass("hidden__");
});
```

```css
.hidden__ {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container__projects" id="commercial">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 animated slideInLeft thumbs">
      <img class="project__images" src="img/commercial/amadeus/a1.jpg" />
      <span class="project__description hidden__">Amadeus Headquarters</span><br>
      <span class="project__description__small hidden__">Interior Design &amp; Supply Services</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 animated slideInRight thumbs">
      <img class="project__images" src="img/commercial/nadine/a1.jpg" />
      <span class="project__description hidden__">Nadine Jewellery</span><br>
      <span class="project__description__small hidden__">Interior Design Supply &amp; Execution</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That being said, it's worth noting that this can be done much more efficiently by using CSS alone:

```css
.hidden__ {
  display: none;
}

.thumbs:hover .project__description,
.thumbs:hover .project__description__small {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container__projects" id="commercial">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 animated slideInLeft thumbs">
      <img class="project__images" src="img/commercial/amadeus/a1.jpg" />
      <span class="project__description hidden__">Amadeus Headquarters</span><br>
      <span class="project__description__small hidden__">Interior Design &amp; Supply Services</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 animated slideInRight thumbs">
      <img class="project__images" src="img/commercial/nadine/a1.jpg" />
      <span class="project__description hidden__">Nadine Jewellery</span><br>
      <span class="project__description__small hidden__">Interior Design Supply &amp; Execution</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: so its fine if i did like this:

.thumbs:hover .project__description,
.thumbs:hover .project__description__small,
.thumbs2:hover .project__description2,
.thumbs2:hover .project__description__small2{
  display: inline;
}

Comment: Well that would work, but as I stated in the question, just put the same class on all the `thumb` and child `span` elements. That way the 4 lines of CSS I showed in the answer above will work for an infinite number of `.thumb` collections.